# Angular app taking a while to apply CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

The angular app that I am working on takes a while to apply the CSS. When any page first loads (or from refresh), everything is displayed as raw html (unordered lists, etc) like : [image]

Here is the network log : [image]
[image]
[image]

Not sure what the root cause of this is and what the best way to resolve it would be.

Comment: You could get a better hint if you test it with https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to resolve it is to use a loading .gif which will be displayed until all elements of the page have been loaded.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Loading div with some CSS and possibly text to let the user know the page is loading -->
<div class="loading"></div> 

<!-- Content div which will have the hidden class removed after the page has been fully loaded and rendered -->
<div class="content hidden"></div>
```

When the **hidden** class is removed from **.content**, it should be applied to **.loading**.